# How do I create a spreadsheet with rows, colums, headers and editable data?

Tags: actionscript-3

I was trying to create a spreadsheet in as3. I tried to do it with grid column , but was not able to add any row header. My requirement was to create a spreadsheet like format with column headers and row headers and I have to add editable data to each cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [project](https://code.google.com/p/flexspreadsheet/) will help.
hope that someone will try to upgrade the code to Apache flex and commit on github.